# Git add and commit with Python script running on GitHub Actions

Tags: python, git, github-actions

I want to add and commit a file with Python script to a repo running on the GitHub Actions server.
I am committing a file by running the following in my `main.py` file:

```py
import os
FILE = './file.txt'
os.system(f'git add {FILE}')
os.system("git commit -m 'update file'")
```

On GitHub actions, I am running Python script as:

```
- name: Commit file
    run: python commit_file.py
```

But there isn't any scripts commits on the repo master branch after GitHub actions run.

On my local machine, `os.system("git commit -m 'update file'")` command is running normally, and I can verify that the commit exist with the `git log` command. On the GitHub actions, the following error occurs:

```sh
Run Commit file
python commit_file.py
Author identity unknown

*** Please tell me who you are.

Run

  git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
  git config --global user.name "Your Name"

to set your account's default identity.
Omit --global to set the identity only in this repository.

fatal: empty ident name (for <runner@fv-az112-319.bzi55m0t1ufu323ye4cn5ktith.xx.internal.cloudapp.net>) not allowed
```

EDIT:
I've added two more lines which will configure git credentials:

```py
os.system('git config --global user.email "you@example.com"')
os.system('git config --global user.name "GitHub Actions"')
```

and now, the warnings are gone, but there is still no commit on the repo.

Comment: Where isn't any commit? Please show a [mre].

Comment: There isn't any script commits on the repo master branch.

Comment: Which repo? On your computer? At GitHub? Where is the Python file executed? Are you on the master branch before executing `git commit`? Was there any change in `file.txt` to commit to begin with? What is the output of the `git commit` command?

Comment: Repo is located on the GitHub and the GitHub Actions will pull the repo and run user specified commands. Python file is located in the repo root dir (the same dir where the .git folder is located). I am committing on every file change. File change status is handled internally. On my local machine `git commit` command returns commit success and I can verify it with the `git log` command. On the Github actions, `git commit` command doesn't output anything, nor does `git add file`.

Comment: It's as the error says Ivan, you need to configure the user email and name using `git config` when you want to commit a new file to a repo using github action. Those values can be fake, hardcoded or depend on a variable. You just need to add those 2 command lines **before** the git add and the git commit commands in your python script.

Comment: @GuiFalourd I've added two more lines (see post Edit) that will configure git but still the same problem persist.

Comment: Does the file.txt appear on the branch if you perform a `git push` at the end of the script?

Comment: Oh, I forgot to push the committed file with `os.system("git push")`. Thank you @GuiFalourd

Comment: Great! If the question reopens, I'll add this answer as official :)

Comment: @GuiFalourd Just cast the third vote to reopen the question, but one might argue this is caused by the equivalent of a typo, so the question might get closed again...

Comment: Thanks, I added the answer before this happening then 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's as the error states, you need to configure the user email and name using `git config` when you want to commit a new file to a repo using github action.

*Note: Those values can be fake, hardcoded or depend on a variable.*

You just need to add those 2 command lines before the git add and the git commit commands in your python script.

Moreover, you will need to perform a `git push` at the end of the script for the file to appear on the repository branch at the end of the workflow run.